# Grepping a phrase when it is a variable

Tags: bash, grep

I have a master file which I'm using as a lookup and I have search strings that are phrases.

My current attempt has been

```
for i in `cat list`              #list contains the phrases that I'm looking for
do 
grep $i master.file
done
```

However since my initial search items ($i in this case) is a phrase, I am getting a lot of mismatches. For instance if the phrase is "Blah for the" then I get a lot of matches which have "the" or "for" in them but not the full pattern. From the command line I can do

```
grep "Blah for the" master.file
```

which gives me meaningful results.
How do I achieve the same results from within the script?

One possible solution is to sed away the spaces in my phrase and also in my master file. But that gets ugly.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Just use `grep -f list master.file`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, that seems to be the answer I was looking for. However, when I tried this, the order of the results got messed up. i.e. if there were 10 phrases in "list", the answer that I got with your line gives me matches in the wrong order. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Never use unquoted variables (unless you can bet a $ bill on you knowing what you are doing; that's what $ in the variable syntax stands for). `"$i"`. And of course `\`cat whatever\`` won't work here. Use `read` in a loop.

Comment: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and use `$(..)` instead of backticks and always quote your variables. I recommend you read a shell programming book (e.g. Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson) and/or tutorial to get the fundamentals.

Comment: @n.m. - Thanks for all the help! The main issue was the unquoted variable in grep. I've been using bash for almost a year but never ever had a problem with leaving my variables unquoted. Nobody ever taught me this and I never faced any errors. Thanks a ton, I'm going to remember this!

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. I did some intense reading and also went through the bash pitfalls book/document. Learnt a lot of basics that I had never really thought I'd need. I was managing without any errors but the code I was writing was inherently 'buggy'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities. If I understood that correctly, you want to loop over lines not words in your file. Two possible ways are pointed out here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file

You can either use `IFS=$'\n'` to make newlines the only seperator and otherwise use the same code. The other possibility that was pointed out in the linked answer as well is to use `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    grep "$i" master.file
done < list
```

Comment: This worked. The unquoted variable in grep was the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Scripts that produce the output you expected given some specific input are the starting point to finding an answer, not the end point. This will be immensely slow compared to http://stackoverflow.com/a/38553616/1745001. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 3):

`grep` has the `-f` option read newline separated patterns from a file:

```
grep -f list master.file
```

Also note that, if you want to search for fixed strings rather than Regex patterns, you also need the `-F` option:

```
grep -Ff list master.file
```

Comment: Is it the other way the op is looking for? :)